# React-bootstrap form only lets me type if value is set to this.state.value?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap for the first time and I was attempting to use their form component as discussed here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms

Currently in my component my code looks like this:

```
       <form>
        <FormGroup controlId="formEmail" >
          <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.loginInput.email}
            placeholder="Email"
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="formPassword" >
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.loginInput.password}
            placeholder="Password"
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
```

The form renders properly exactly as expected based on the instructions on the reat-bootstrap page, but when I attempt to type in the inputs nothing happens. I can only type into the input if i change the following line from `value={this.state.loginInput.password}` to `value={this.state.value}`

If i try to make `this.state.value` into anything else except `value` it won't work. My constructor looks like this btw:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      loginInput: {
        email: '',
        password: '',
      },
    };
```

Is there a reason react-bootstrap isn't letting me use my own value there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution appears to be that `FormControl` requires me to have an `OnChange` function other wise the input field is read only? That seems like strange behavior but merely changing my form to have an onChange event defined allowed the form to work as expected.

```
        <FormGroup controlId="formPassword" >
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.loginInput.password}
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
```

Comment: I guess expectation in your original question was two way binding which is not the case with React.

Comment: Yes that is actually exactly what i assumed thank you for pointing that out. I actually didn't realize that, but now reflecting on how this works i see that now.